# Access current request headers from inside a dll function

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I think this should be fairly simple but I can't find anything on google on this for some reason

I have a WebAPi 2.0 controller (type:ApiController) that can read the read the request headers

```
Request.Headers.GetValues("SomeHeader");
```

In the same project I have another class (AccessFactory) that I would like to access the headers from.

Reason being that I would not want to do the same code for every function call to read all the needed headers at the point where they are actually needed.

Comment: would it make sense to pass the request object, or the relevant subset of header values, into your DLL method? Presumably they're something telling it about the current context? If this method is in a DLL, is it something that could be re-used in a non-web app? If so then might make sense to just pass values, rather than relying on web-specific objects. Dunno, depends on your design. But I think within a separate project you can still get access to the current HTTP context (and thus the request headers), if you want to do it that way then  `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is what you need

Comment: Done the trick nicely thank you. Please make an answer so I can accept it. This factory is a super-set of the underlying infrastructure and will be used only in the web part so it is safe to bound it to the web :)

Comment: done. I've left in the comment about web stuff just for future readers but feel free to ignore it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within a separate project / DLL you can still get access to the current HTTP context (and thus the request headers) using the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` object.

As an aside, I would add that if this DLL is meant to be re-usable across different applications, then consider whether it will be used on non-web applications, and if so you should avoid making dependencies on a web-based context like this. Instead you might consider passing in the header values you need as simple types, or in a custom object. That way they can indicate the context, but a non-web app could pass in equivalent contextual values of its own. But that's a separate design decision depending on the exact purpose and how you intend to use this DLL library in future.